# Exceeded the maximum number of allowed receivers per partition Error in eventhub

Tags: python, azure-eventhub, receiver

Like the code below, I am continuously receiving data from azure eventhub. Often I am seeing the error saying "Exceeded the maximum number of allowed receivers per partition" which I know where it comes from.

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import time
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset

logger = logging.getLogger("azure")

ADDRESS = ""
USER = ""
KEY = ""

CONSUMER_GROUP = "$default"
OFFSET = Offset("@latest")
PARTITION = "0"

total = 0
last_sn = -1
last_offset = "-1"
client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)

receiver = client.add_receiver(CONSUMER_GROUP, PARTITION, prefetch=0, offset=OFFSET)    
client.run()
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    for event_data in receiver.receive(timeout=5000):
        print("Received: {}".format(event_data.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')))
        a = event_data.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')
        total += 1
    end_time = time.time()
    run_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Received {} messages in {} seconds".format(total, run_time))
```

The line here is the one that add receiver and if I add more than five reciever, it hits the limit of the possible number of receiver per partition.

```
receiver = client.add_receiver(CONSUMER_GROUP, PARTITION, prefetch=0
```

1. So, I tried to remove receiver with functions in it.
   like using `receiver.client.clients.remove` or `receiver.client.clients.clear()`, to clear the receivers added in it before. However, none of these methods seems to work.

The reason why I see this error is that because I run the whole code above whenever I need to stop running script to debug, so whenever I re-run it, I have to run the line  `receiver = client.add_receiver(CONSUMER_GROUP, PARTITION, prefetch=0`

2. I also tried to run only part of the code below "add_receiver" line

```
client.run()
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    for event_data in receiver.receive(timeout=5000):
        print("Received: {}".format(event_data.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')))
        a = event_data.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')
        total += 1
    end_time = time.time()
    run_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Received {} messages in {} seconds".format(total, run_time))
```

However, I see another error saying that 
`EventHubError: This receive handler is now closed.`

Any possible ways to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi Brian, can you explain more about this ''if I add more then five reciever, it hits the limit of xxxx"?

Comment: @IvanYang That means that Azure event hub limits the number of receivers per one consumer and I am hitting that limit.

Comment: @IvanYang Sorry, there was a typo.

Comment: You said you know where this error come from. Can you please explain it to me? I'm having the same error and just started recently with azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling, I think this may be a solution to this issue.

For the line 22 above, I could simplly add 'keep_alive' input to it, something like:

```
receiver = client.add_receiver(CONSUMER_GROUP, PARTITION, prefetch=0, offset=OFFSET, keep_alive = 10000000)
```

In this way, I can leave the client receiver opened and not get the error message "EventHubError: This receive handler is now closed.", then simply run the only part from below:

```
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    for event_data in receiver.receive(timeout=5000):
        print("Received: {}".format(event_data.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')))
        a = event_data.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')
        total += 1
    end_time = time.time()
    run_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Received {} messages in {} seconds".format(total, run_time))
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem but using the Nodejs API. There no argument keep_alive for the nodejs code. Do you know how to solve this? any help is appreciated. I'm looking for one week now for a solution